# Rails DB based on param

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How to specify DB connection for a specific session, based on parameter. For example, app lives from September to September. after it's live cycle over last year will be stored in old db, and a new db will be created for a new live cycle.
 The api will work like this: `domain.com/2013/#/backbone_urls`. in the place of 2013, may be stored any year, based on what Active record will create connection with particular db, so all queries for this user was from this db. This may be hard issue, or wrong solution for this.

Comment: Yes, it's the wrong solution. Better use 1 database and have a year column for relevant records. The you can use scopes to get the info for different years.

Comment: And what if as a result I will be able to modify any record in any db by simply passing url param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection ...
```

Anytime you need to switch DB, so for your case:

```
new_config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env].clone
new_config['database'] = "new_db_#{Date.today.year}"
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection new_config
```

You could execute these three lines could be executed by a scheduler. But what I don't know is how exactly to do it, since you will need a scheduler that runs "inside" your Rails application.

According whether this is a good or wrong solution, I opine– read don't know – it has pros and cons, you will have several small databases instead a big one, so you won't have easy access to search all data, but you won't have to handle big databases.

Comment: This is a good start for solving this issue. Thanks!